# How to create a filter dropdown using jquery-footable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, footable

I'm utilizing footable on an html table. Although I can filter the footable using the search inbox, I would like to create a dropdown that can filter.

Within the dropdown, I'm trying to create three ('Enable','Disabled','Low stock') which filter for the value 'Enable','Disabled','Low stock' respectively within the 'Status' column.

After reading [through this documentation](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/filter-dropdown.html), I've implemented the below function ([see codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGRRxR?editors=1000))

```
  FooTable.MyFiltering = FooTable.Filtering.extend({
    construct: function(instance){
        this._super(instance);
        this.modeles = ['Enable','Disabled','Low stock'];
        this.def = 'Any Status';
        this.$status = null;
    },
    $create: function(){
        this._super();
        var self = this,
            $form_grp = $('<div/>', {'class': 'form-group'})
                .append($('<label/>', {'class': 'sr-only', text: 'Status'}))
                .prependTo(self.$form);

        self.$status = $('<select/>', { 'class': 'form-control' })
            .on('change', {self: self}, self._onStatusDropdownChanged)
            .append($('<option/>', {text: self.def}))
            .appendTo($form_grp);

        $.each(self.statuses, function(i, status){
            self.$status.append($('<option/>').text(status));
        });
    },
    _onStatusDropdownChanged: function(e){
        var self = e.data.self,
            selected = $(this).val();
        if (selected !== self.def){
            self.addFilter('status', selected, ['status']);
        } else {
            self.removeFilter('status');
        }
        self.filter();
    },
    draw: function(){
        this._super();
        var status = this.find('status');
        if (status instanceof FooTable.Filter){
            this.$status.val(status.query.val());
        } else {
            this.$status.val(this.def);
        }
    }
});

  $('.table').footable({
    components: {
        filtering: FooTable.MyFiltering
    }
});
```

The filter does not show up even when adding the above javascript.

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://kuwaitpolitics.org/FooTable/demos/filtering.htm#docs) demonstrates how to trigger a custom filter and see [codepen here](https://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/MERMEP?editors=1000)

The following jquery can be utilized:

```
$( "#enable_button" ).click(function() {
   $('.footable').trigger('footable_filter', {filter: "Enable"});
});

$( "#disable_button" ).click(function() {
   $('.footable').trigger('footable_filter', {filter: "Disabled"});
});

$( "#low_button" ).click(function() {
   $('.footable').trigger('footable_filter', {filter: "Low stock"});
});
```